# Python Iterating program

Tags: python, csv, operating-system, xlsx

I am a beginner programmer who is working on my first project. I am trying to create a script that unzips two files and extracts a folder that contains .csv files to a temp directory. I am hoping to import and format those .csv with Xlsx lib. My code is able to do the first part, it unzips all the .csv's perfectly.

I need some pointers on how to iterate over all the .csv's on the temp folder and copy the data of each .csv to an excel spreadsheet. I must note that the .csv files have only one row with 5 columns of data. Here is what I have:

```
   for zfiles in glob.glob("*.zip"):
       with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiles, 'r') as myS:
           myS.extractall(tempDir)
           os.chdir(tempDir)
           for z in glob.glob("*.zip"):
               with zipfile.ZipFile(z, 'r') as mySecondS:
                   mySecondS.extractall()
```

Thank you!

Comment: The second for looks for zip files unzipped from the first file. Probably not what you want. You probably want to glob("*.csv") next. If the caves are in subdirectories, os.path.walk will help. I don't know if you already have a lib to convert to xslx, but the openpyxl package, or the python win32 package (use the excel com objects similar to vb examples) can help.

Comment: Yes, there was a second zip that I needed to access. Will os.path.walk access a zip file? I have xlsxwriter for the conversion but haven't figured out a way to iterate over the .csv files and import the data to an excel spreadsheet.  Thanks